# Can peripheral advertisement/broadcasting be reactivated in the background?

Tags: ios7, core-location, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

From what I understand, once an app is terminated by iOS for memory use, my app will stop advertising as a peripheral (even if I've enabled the peripheral in the background).

Is it possible to reactivate the peripheral advertisement when my app is woken in the background for a periodic server update, or in the case of using Significant Location Changes where the app is woken in the background every time the phone moves to a new location?

Comment: Good question, would be great if you tried and reported back on results.

Comment: Have you tried State Preservation/Restoration for a `CBPeripheralManager` as described in Apple's [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html)? The doc leans slightly towards `CBCentralManager` examples but you should be able to figure it out. Try to give it a shot. The system has the ability to store the advertisement data/services and characteristics/subscribed centrals.